# Racket - Importing OpenCL

Tags: linux, scheme, opencl, racket

I am attempting to learn OpenCL and I installed the OpenCL FFI using `raco pkg install opencl`, but I am now getting a strange error when I try to use the package:

```
clGetPlatformIDs: Undefined error: -1001
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/arrow-val-first.rkt:255:18
   /home/lb/Dropbox/workspace/misc/opencl-test.rkt: [running body]
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
#lang racket
(require opencl/c)
(displayln (clGetPlatformIDs:count))
```

And furthermore, when I run `raco test --drdr -p opencl`, I get fails on 26/61 of the tests.

I am running Racket 6.1.1 on Arch Linux (64 bit).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by installing the `beignet` package from the Arch User Repository. This package conflicted with my installation of libcl, which it also provides. I removed my extraneous libcl with `sudo pacman -R -dd libcl` to skip dependency checks.

After sucessfully installing `beignet`, `raco test --drdr -p opencl` reports 15/61 errors, and the above code runs.